# Can I run line_profiler over a pytest test?

Tags: python, pytest, cprofile

I have identified some long running pytest tests with

```
py.test --durations=10
```

I would like to instrument one of those tests now with something like line_profiler or cprofile.  I really want to get the profile data from the test itself as the pytest setup or tear down could well be part of what is slow.

However given how line_profiler or cprofile is typically involved it isn't clear to me how to make them work with pytest.

Answer (score 62):

Run pytest like this:

```
python3 -m cProfile -o profile -m pytest
```

You can even pass in optional arguments:

```
python3 -m cProfile -o profile -m pytest tests/worker/test_tasks.py -s campaigns
```

This will create a binary file called `profile` in your current directory. This can be analyzed with pstats:

```
import pstats
p = pstats.Stats('profile')
p.strip_dirs()
p.sort_stats('cumtime')
p.print_stats(50)
```

This will print the 50 lines with the longest cumulative duration.

Comment: I've tried to get this working on Windows. But if fails on the first command, saying: "no such file of directory '(which'". I tried to give the absolute path to the py.test.exe binary but I get a different error: "TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes". I got the profiling running by adding a pytest.main call in the test module. Any suggestions how to get it running from the command line on Windows?

Comment: From command line: ``python -c "import pstats; pstats.Stats('profile').strip_dirs().sort_stats('cumtime').print_stats(50)"``

Comment: `python -m cProfile -o profile -m pytest` gives `cProfile.py: error: no such option: -m`. Try `python3 -m cProfile -o profile $(which py.test)` instead.

Answer (score 21):

To get `cProfile` and `line_profiler` to work with `py.test` code, I did two things:

1. Extended the py.test test code with a call to pytest.main(), which made it executable with the python interpreter as the main driver:

   ```
   # pytest_test.py:
   @profile # for line_profiler only
   def test_example():
       x = 3**32
       assert x == 1853020188851841

   # for profiling with cProfile and line_profiler
   import pytest
   pytest.main(__file__)
   ```

   Now you can run this test without `py.test` as the main driver using other tools:

   ```
   $ kernprof.py -l pytest_test.py
   $ python -m line_profiler pytest_test.py.lprof
   ```

   or

   ```
   $ python -m cProfile pytest_test.py
   ```
2. To profile py.test-specific functions such as `pytest_funcarg*()` with `line_profiler` I split them in two to avoid confusion between `py.test` and `line_profiler`:

   ```
   def pytest_funcarg__foo(request):
       return foo(request)

   @profile
   def foo(request):
   ...
   ```

The same method works for [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler).

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried the [pytest-profiling](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-profiling/?) plugin?

Comment: This is a really nice plugin which makes profiling really simple, but AFAIK it does not do line profiling

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote [pytest-line-profiler](https://github.com/mgaitan/pytest-line-profiler) that may be useful. It's not battle tested, so please give me feedback (and help).

Comment: It breaks some of my tests even when not used, just installed.

Comment: could you open an issue with an example? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This also works with `pyinstrument`:

```
pyinstrument -m pytest test.py
```